# How can we deduce that a point is stable if the eigenvalues of J are negative?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f : \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, and consider the dynamical system

$$\dfrac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = f(\mathbf{x})$$

If $\mathbf{x}_1$ is an equilibrium point, then consider perturbations from this point, $\varepsilon (t)$.  It can be shown that

$$\dfrac{d(\mathbf{x}_1+\varepsilon (t))}{dt} = f(\mathbf{x}_1 +\varepsilon (t))   \implies    \dfrac{d \varepsilon}{dt} = J(\mathbf{x}_1)\varepsilon + O(\mid \varepsilon \mid^2)$$

Why is it that $\mid \varepsilon(t) \mid \rightarrow 0$ if the eigenvalues of J are negative? How can we deduce which eigenvalue will result in the best approximation $e^{\lambda t}$?

In other words, if the solution to $\dfrac{d \varepsilon}{dt} = J(\mathbf{x}_1)\varepsilon$ is $\varepsilon = \vec{\eta}e^{\lambda t}$, how do we know which $\lambda$ to use?

Comment: Solution to the last equation would be $\epsilon = e^{J(x_1) t}~ \hat{\eta}$, where $e^{J(x_1)}$ denotes matrix exponentiation.

Comment: Another answer is _Lyapunov function_. Here the same Lyapunov function that suits linear case is a good choice for nonlinear case.

Comment: Also, the solution to $\frac{d\epsilon}{dt} = J(x_1) \epsilon$ is $\exp(J(x_1)t) \epsilon_0$.